# Return the value to 0 after reaching specific value in Python and Rpi

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi, encoder

I have an encoder attached to Raspberrypi. The motor is connected to arduino, based on the value of encoder, the motor will function. I am able to send the value from rpi to arduino using Serial communication(USB). The problem is, the value keeps on increasing (eg. 1, 2, 3, .....). I want that the value of the encoder should start from 0 once it reads 10 as shown in code below. Help would be appreciated.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
#ser.write(b'0')
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(True)

pin_A = 17
pin_B = 18

Encoder_Count = 0
A_Pos2=0
GPIO.setup (pin_A, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup (pin_B, GPIO.IN)
A_Pos = 0
A_Last = "00"
STATE = {"0001":1,"0010":-1,"0100":-1,"0111":1,"1000":1,"1011":-1, "1101":-1, "1110":1}     

def Encoder1(channel1):
    global Encoder_Count,A_Pos,A_Last,STATE
    now = str(GPIO.input(17)) + str(GPIO.input(18))
    key = A_Last + now
    if key in STATE:
            direction = STATE[key]
            A_Last = now
            A_Pos +=direction


GPIO.add_event_detect (pin_A, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Encoder1)  
GPIO.add_event_detect (pin_B, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Encoder1)
#A_Pos2=0

while(1):
   # ser.write(b'1')
    A_Pos2= A_Pos/(1600)
    print (A_Pos2)
    if (A_Pos2 >10):
    ser.write(b'0')
        time.sleep(0.01)


GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Can't you just use modulo operator? `value = value % 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with modulo operation, unless i am missing something:

```
if (A_Pos2 >10):
    A_Pos2 = A_Pos2 % 10
```

That will reset `A_Pos2` to 0 once it reaches 10.